# How to use hide() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide a div the id of which I stored in a variable named 'post_container_id'. My code is:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // Add event listener to following button
    document.querySelectorAll('.post-edit').forEach(item => {
        var itemid = item.getAttribute('id').slice(5,)
        item.addEventListener('click', () => edit_post(itemid));
    })
    
  });

function edit_post(itemid) {
    var post_container_id = `#post-container-${itemid}`;
    (function(){
        $(post_container_id).hide(1000);
      });
};
```

This does not hide the div. It does not throw any error either. The function does get triggered (I checked it by logging to console). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you provided an [mcve] — including the HTML you are trying to operate on — use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake here:

```
(function(){
  $(post_container_id).hide(1000);
});
```

You are just declaring the function, you should also call it:

```
(function(){
  $(post_container_id).hide(1000);
})();
```

Also, the callback is useless in this case, you can just solve it as:

```js
function edit_post(itemid) {
   var post_container_id = `#post-container-${itemid}`;
   $(post_container_id).hide(1000);
};

$("#hide").click(function(){
  edit_post(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post-container-1">secret</div>
<button id="hide">Click to hide</button>
```

Comment: From the context I would expect the first example to be a jQuery document.ready handler that's just missing the leading `$`, not an IIFE.

Comment: Probably you right, still why put a document.ready inside another callback

Comment: That does it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use vanilla JavaScript to hide/show the element directly by changing the style display property. As follows

```
function edit_post(itemid) {
    const post_container_id = document.querySelectorAll(`#post-container-${itemid}`);
    post_container_id.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: Yes, I realized that later on. This is much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

Without jQuery,

```
document.getElementById(post_container_id).style.display = "none"
```